# CKEditor Textarea not displaying on live server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for my textareas and I am able to see the editor when I run the application locally, however, when I publish the application to the live server the editor is not visable.
I just see the label for the textarea and then there is a space where the editor should be.

I am using the class attribute to replace my textareas like so

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostContent, new { @class="ckeditor" })
```

And this is rendering the html correctly

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="20" id="PostContent" name="PostContent" rows="2">
```

I am using ckeditor 4.0 and have tested this in IE as well as chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this by removing the reference to the bundle for ckeditor and replacing it with a direct link to the ckeditor.js

Answer (score 1):

You still can add this script to bundle, however ckeditor loads all additional needed scripts, css, language files by itself, based on path for main script file. Puting it into bundle changed the path and plugin couldn't find needed content.

to make it work you need to override base path for editor:
http://cdn-source.docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath

Answer (score -1):

If you are going tu use the text area like that:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostContent, new { @class="ckeditor" })
```

The javascript call should look like that:

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('PostContent');
```

CKEDITOR replace looks for the name attribute of the text area, not the class.

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT:**

This solution is only for explicit editor replace, not automatic replace.

source: http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/7664/_samples/replacebyclass.html

(thanks to AlfonsoML)

Comment: No, he's using the automatic replace method so he doesn't need to call CKEDITOR.replace. The official docs site is down at the moment so I can't add the link to the API :-(